# Offline webpages reader/browser for iPad iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, web-browser

Is there an app for iPad/iPhone that allows me to save an entire webpage including JavaScript, AJAX actions, images, etc., and open it when offline?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackapps.com/questions/3614/offline-webpages-reader-saver-for-ipad - same user at same time?

Comment: do you just want to read the pages?

Answer (score 1):

[Offline Pages](http://offlinepag.es) lets users save entire web pages for offline reading, including formatting and images; 4.99 USD on Apple App Store.

[Open in App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/offline-pages/id364859644?mt=8)

Comment: Do you just want to read the pages later?